# How to resolve compiler error in directx and c++

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am reading Frank D Lunas' book on 3d game programming, and I am trying to get the samples working. Firstly, when I open the project there are various header files, and when you try to compile, it issues an error message like 'Cannot open include file: 'd3dx11.h': No such file or directory' even though it is there. When you delete it and replace it with a header file with the same name, the error goes away. Secondly, when you do that for all the header files and compile it issues an error message saying something like it cannot open a file called 'Effects11d'. What is the issue?

Comment: The first issues sound like different encoding or invisible characters. `Effects11d` is library

Comment: Do you know how to get it to work?

Comment: Find and link the library.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 you need to enable Game Development with DirectX in c++

Answer (score 0):

Frank Luna's book assumes you are using the (now deprecated) [DirectX SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-). Starting with VS 2010, you have to manually add the include/lib paths to the VC++ Directories settings of Visual Studio to access it. The key thing is with VS 2012 or later, you need to list the `DXSDK_DIR` paths *last* because everything in the Windows SDK is now newer than it.

Details on the bottom of [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/book-recommendations/) for more notes.